# 1 value missing from Drop down parameter list (69)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report that for some odd reason wants to ignore the existence of a value. All of the other values are present, it is just the 69 value that happens to be missing within SSRS.

In SSMS the value is there.

I am feeding the parameter (Allow Blank/ allow Multiple Values) from a Dataset query, the query is:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SELECT DISTINCT hrcl.rvalue
FROM dbo.herpaderpcl hrcl 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ANY'
```

When this is run against SSMS I am given 137 rows as the return. In SSRS I am only returned 136.

Everything else on the report works great. I also rewrote it slowly removing all other parameters to see if there was a conflict. There is not. It is purely this one Dataset/ Parameter that is acting up

Here is a partial screen shot of what the parameter drop down looks like, and where 69 should be showing up, but isn't.

[image]

Comment: There's not enough information here to determine what the problem might be. The query you provided does not appear to match the list you showed because the "ANY" value is also missing. SSRS doesn't change query results, it uses whatever SQL Server returns. If there are cascading parameters or something else going on, it would help to show that so someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I am dynamically creating the table listing, and the starting point for this choice does not have this value in it.

I am attempting to create a new dataset, by dynamically populating this set, based off of the original choice.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue or are you trying to add clarification to your problem?

Comment: Issue is resolved, but there isn't a good explanation as to how it is because of how SSRS looks at the first DB it can get values from, instead of across all DB's in an Expression